# Hola, tengo el siguiente error --> Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#version' must be declared in an enclosing class

Tags: opengl, glsl

El siguiente código lo tengo separado en dos archivos, cada uno con extensión .glsl
estoy trabajando en threejs, según la consola de chrome el error está en fragment.glsl.

el error -->

Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#version' must be declared in an enclosing class

traté de solucionarlo con todo tipo de plugins

por favor si alguien me puede ayudara solucionar este error!! gracias!!

```
//vertex extensión .glsl

#version 450 es 

uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec3 spectrum;
uniform mat4 mvp;

in vec4 a_position;
in vec3 a_normal;
in vec2 a_texcoord;

out VertexData {
    vec4 v_position;
    vec3 v_normal;
    vec2 v_texcoord;
} outData;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * a_position;

    outData.v_position = a_position;
    outData.v_normal = a_normal;
    outData.v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}



// fragment extensión .glsl

 #version 450 es 

uniform float time;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec3 spectrum;

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;
uniform sampler2D texture3;
uniform sampler2D prevFrame;
uniform sampler2D prevPass;

in VertexData {
    vec4 v_position;
    vec3 v_normal;
    vec2 v_texcoord;
} inData;

uniform vec4 fragColor;

void main(void) {
    vec2 uv = -1. + 2. * inData.v_texcoord;
    fragColor = vec4(abs(sin(cos(time + 3. * uv.y) * 2. * uv.x + time)), abs(cos(sin(time + 2. * uv.x) * 3. * uv.y + time)), spectrum.x * 100., 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Eso parece un error de javascript. A caso estás intenta cargar el código como si fuera javascript?